# Store a set of protobufs on disk

Tags: serialization, storage, protocol-buffers, thrift

I am using protobuf as a serializer to format data on disk. I may have a large set of protobuf object, say, millions of them. what is the best choice to layout them on disk? the protobuf objects will be read sequentially one by one or random accessed read by a external index.

I used to use lenghth(int)+protobuf_object+length(int).... format, but it failed if one of the protobuf happens to be dirty. and if many of the protobuf object are small, it may have some overhead.

Comment: It could be useful to know how you need to access the data: just read sequentially, random access, random writes, search by some criterion?

Comment: define "it failed when one of the protobuf is dirty"; do you mean "I couldn't just overwrite that part of the file, because if the length changes there is either a gap in the file (with garbage) or it overwrites the next bit of data"?

Comment: yes i just want to read it sequentially, or seek according the 'index' put in the file. random write is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need sequential access, the easiest way to store multiple messages is to write the size of the object before it, as reccomended by the documentation: http://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming

For example, you can create a class 'MessagesFile' with the following member functions to open, read and write your messages:

```
// File is opened using append mode and wrapped into
// a FileOutputStream and a CodedOutputStream
bool Open(const std::string& filename,
          int buffer_size = kDefaultBufferSize) {

    file_ = open(filename.c_str(),
                 O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, // open mode
                 S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_ISUID); //file permissions

    if (file_ != -1) {
        file_ostream_ = new FileOutputStream(file_, buffer_size);
        ostream_ = new CodedOutputStream(file_ostream_);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Code for append a new message
bool Serialize(const google::protobuf::Message& message) {
    ostream_->WriteLittleEndian32(message.ByteSize());
    return message.SerializeToCodedStream(ostream_);
}

// Code for reading a message using a FileInputStream
// wrapped into a CodedInputStream 
bool Next(google::protobuf::Message *msg) {
    google::protobuf::uint32 size;
    bool has_next = istream_->ReadLittleEndian32(&size);
    if(!has_next) {
        return false;
    } else {
        CodedInputStream::Limit msgLimit = istream_->PushLimit(size);
        if ( msg->ParseFromCodedStream(istream_) ) {
            istream_->PopLimit(msgLimit);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, to write your messagges use:

```
MessagesFile file;
reader.Open("your_file.dat");

file.Serialize(your_message1);
file.Serialize(your_message2);
...
// close the file
```

To read all your messages:

```
MessagesFile reader;
reader.Open("your_file.dat");

MyMsg msg;
while( reader.Next(&msg) ) {
    // user your message
}
...
// close the file
```

Answer (score 2):

(I hope I've understood your question correctly and my response fits your use case!)

One technique for storing an arbitrary stream of Protocol Buffer messages to disk is to define a wrapper message where all fields are defined as `repeated` (which implies `optional`), and then when you read in your bytes, you get an instance of the wrapper class and call the hasX() methods on it to find what you actually have. The problem with this approach in your case is that you get no random access and no real streaming (all messages of type `Foo` will be together, followed by all `Bar`s) and if your data is too big you won't be able to fit the whole lot into memory.

In fact you're basically asking for a methodology for storing any kind of data in such a way that it can be streamed or randomly accessed. This a generic problem, rather than something that is specific to Protocol Buffers.

Your problems are:

- delimiting records... (see note)
- ...in such a way that damage can be detected and either tolerated or repaired...
- ...while maintaining an index to allow random access

You would probably use the index to permit some kind of integrity checks, but even that requires a mechanism to ensure that the index and the data correspond and remain in sync.

Therefore, it may not be the ideal solution, but one way to achieve what you want, especially if integrity is a problem, is to store this information in a database that permits the storage of binary data and can return that data quickly. The question of random access and data integrity would then become the responsibility of the database provider. Any traditional database that is capable of storing BLOBs would be able to do it, though I'd also consider storing it in NoSQL such as MongoDB.

### Note

If you define your Protocol Buffers carefully (ie you know the types and lengths of the fields being stored) then you would not actually need to delimit your records as their length would never change. However, this would break one of the features of Protocol Buffers, namely its future-proof nature. If you designed a `.proto` in such a way that the message size was fixed, you'd not be able to add new fields and still fit into the same file format, safely saying that each new message begins after x bytes.